# Postgres: Obtener que parte es un registro dentro de un conjunto

Tags: sql, postgresql

Buen día, estoy tratando de obtener o calcular la información de cada registro dentro de un conjunto (cuota y valor parcial), lo explico a continuación con un ejemplo:

```
| id_pago    |  fecha      | valor |
|:-----------|------------:|:-----:|
| 910006603  | 2017-04-19  | 30    |
| 910006603  | 2017-04-21  | 30    |
| 910006603  | 2017-04-23  | 30    |
| 910006603  | 2017-04-25  | 30    |  
| 910006604  | 2017-04-14  | 45    | 
| 910006604  | 2017-04-18  | 45    |
```

Con esta información debo agregar otras dos columnas, que indiquen la cuota y el valor parcial de ésta, a manera que resulte:

```
| id_pago    |  fecha      | valor | cuota | parcial|
|:-----------|------------:|:-----:|:-----:|:------:|
| 910006603  | 2017-04-19  | 30    | 1     | 30     |
| 910006603  | 2017-04-21  | 30    | 2     | 60     |
| 910006603  | 2017-04-23  | 30    | 3     | 90     |
| 910006603  | 2017-04-25  | 30    | 4     | 120    |

| 910006604  | 2017-04-14  | 45    | 1     | 45     | 
| 910006604  | 2017-04-18  | 45    | 2     | 90     |
```

Espero ser lo suficientemente explicito, mil gracias.

Explico el comentario, lo que se requiere es aplicar un `distinct pero que quede en cada fila de acuerdo al modelo que tiene una consulta:

Caso 1: La consulta tiene pagos que se hicieron con cuotas y con parcelas

```
| id_pago    |  fecha      | modelo   | modelos            |
|:-----------|------------:|:--------:|:------------------:|
| 910006603  | 2017-04-19  | cuotas   | [cuotas, parcelas] |
| 910006603  | 2017-04-21  | parcelas | [cuotas, parcelas] |
| 910006603  | 2017-04-23  | cuotas   | [cuotas, parcelas] |
| 910006603  | 2017-04-25  | cuotas   | [cuotas, parcelas] |
| 910006604  | 2017-04-14  | parcelas | [cuotas, parcelas] |
| 910006604  | 2017-04-18  | cuotas   | [cuotas, parcelas] |
```

Caso 2 y 3: La consulta solo trae resultados con un modelo de pagos

```
| id_pago    |  fecha      | modelo   | modelos  |
|:-----------|------------:|:--------:|:--------:|
| 910006605  | 2017-05-19  | cuotas   | [cuotas] |
| 910006605  | 2017-05-21  | cuotas   | [cuotas] |
| 910006605  | 2017-05-23  | cuotas   | [cuotas] |
| 910006605  | 2017-05-25  | cuotas   | [cuotas] |
| 910006606  | 2017-05-14  | cuotas   | [cuotas] |
| 910006606  | 2017-05-18  | cuotas   | [cuotas] |

| id_pago    |  fecha      | modelo   | modelos    |
|:-----------|------------:|:--------:|:----------:|
| 910006607  | 2017-06-19  | parcelas | [parcelas] |
| 910006607  | 2017-06-21  | parcelas | [parcelas] |
| 910006608  | 2017-06-23  | parcelas | [parcelas] |
| 910006608  | 2017-06-25  | parcelas | [parcelas] |
| 910006608  | 2017-06-14  | parcelas | [parcelas] |
| 910006609  | 2017-06-18  | parcelas | [parcelas] |
```

Se obvian los resultados anteriores de las columnas que también se deben mostrar cuota y parcial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes usar `window functions` para esto:

```
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_pago ORDER BY fecha) as cuota,
       SUM(valor) OVER(PARTITION BY id_pago ORDER BY fecha) as parcial
FROM TuTabla;
```

[**Acá hay un demo**](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=de7ac1db49dbc0f3a5868c0917676be3) con el código.

Y los resultados son:

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╦═══════╦═══════╦═════════╗
║  id_pago  ║   fecha    ║ valor ║ cuota ║ parcial ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╬═══════╬═══════╬═════════╣
║ 910006603 ║ 2017-04-19 ║    30 ║     1 ║      30 ║
║ 910006603 ║ 2017-04-21 ║    30 ║     2 ║      60 ║
║ 910006603 ║ 2017-04-23 ║    30 ║     3 ║      90 ║
║ 910006603 ║ 2017-04-25 ║    30 ║     4 ║     120 ║
║ 910006604 ║ 2017-04-14 ║    45 ║     1 ║      45 ║
║ 910006604 ║ 2017-04-18 ║    45 ║     2 ║      90 ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╩═══════╩═══════╩═════════╝
```

Comment: Funcionó de maravilla. Sabes si tuviera otra columna con el modelo de pago, ejemplo cuotas o parcelas, y no diferenciara por `id_pago`, ¿cómo podría agregarlo como otra columna? Es decir tener al final otra columna que dijera modelos y me retornara un arreglo de la forma: [cuotas, parcelas], y en el caso de que en la consulta solo hubiese pagos con cuotas [cuotas] o sólo parcelas [parcelas]. Algo similar a un *distinct*.

Comment: @AndreFontaine Sorry, la verdad no entiendo bien la pregunta. Sería más fácil ver un ejemplo con los datos y el resultado deseado....

Comment: Edité la pregunta original, para no crear una nueva. Mil gracias

Comment: @AndreFontaine Pero en tu edición no queda claro cuál es el dato de la tabla y cuál es el resultado que esperas. También, qué pasa con los datos de tu pregunta original, porque si no está relacionado con eso, pienso que estaría mejor como una pregunta aparte